# Hadoop Fail to Connect to ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am just testing out hadoop by running a wordcount example, but this error came up:

```
14/07/30 12:03:02 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your   
platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/07/30 12:03:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
14/07/30 12:03:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already     
tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 
SECONDS)
14/07/30 12:03:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already   
tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 
SECONDS)
```

Some people on the internet have suggested it's because of the yarn-site.xml file. Mine is:

```
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>128</value>
      <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource     
      Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>1024</value>
      <description>Maximum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource 
      Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
      <value>1</value>
      <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of 
      virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this won't take effect, and the specified value will 
      get allocated the minimum.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
      <value>2</value>
      <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of 
      virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this 
      value.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
      <value>2048</value>
      <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
      <value>2</value>
      <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
```

I ran programs last week and it was working fine, so I really can't figure out what is going on. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give the same answer I gave on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586920/hadoop-connecting-to-resourcemanager-failed/25228657#25228657).

Make sure you've started Yarn. Use this command to start it:

> start-yarn.sh

Then use this command to verify that the Resource Manager is running:

> jps

The output should look something like this:

> 17542 NameNode
>
> 17920 SecondaryNameNode
>
> 22064 Jps
>
> 17703 DataNode
>
> **18226 ResourceManager**
>
> 18363 NodeManager