# Hadoop ResourceManager HA Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032

Tags: hadoop, high-availability, failover, resourcemanager

Extending one of the questions:
[Hadoop: Connecting to ResourceManager failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586920/hadoop-connecting-to-resourcemanager-failed)

Hadoop 2.6.1

I do have ResourceManager HA configured.

When I do kill 'local' ResourceManager (to check the cluster), then the failover occures, and the ResourceManager on other server becomes active. Unfortunatelly, when I try to run a job using 'local' instance nodemanager, it does not 'failover' the request to active ResourceManager.

```
yarn@stg-hadoop106:~$ jps
26738 Jps
23463 DataNode
23943 DFSZKFailoverController
24297 NodeManager
25690 ResourceManager
23710 JournalNode
23310 NameNode

#kill and start ResourceManager, so the failover occur
yarn@stg-hadoop106:~$ kill -9 25690
~/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh  start resourcemanager

yarn@stg-hadoop106:~$ ~/hadoop/bin/yarn  rmadmin -getServiceState rm1
standby
yarn@stg-hadoop106:~$ ~/hadoop/bin/yarn  rmadmin -getServiceState rm2
active

#run my class:

14:56:51.476 [main] INFO  o.apache.samza.job.yarn.ClientHelper - trying to connect to RM 0.0.0.0:8032
2015-10-29 14:56:51 RMProxy [INFO] Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14:56:51.572 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.s.a.util.KerberosName - Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
2015-10-29 14:56:51 NativeCodeLoader [WARN] Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14:56:51.575 [main] DEBUG o.a.hadoop.util.PerformanceAdvisory - Falling back to shell based
2015-10-29 14:56:52 Client [INFO] Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-10-29 14:56:53 Client [INFO] Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

yarn-site.xml

```
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
     <value>clusterstaging</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
     <value>rm1,rm2,rm3</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm1</name>
     <value>stg-hadoop106</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2</name>
     <value>stg-hadoop107</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm3</name>
     <value>stg-hadoop108</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
     <value>A:2181,B:2181,C:2181</value>
 </property>
```

I did not configure

```
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
```

since it should work 'as is' - correct me if I'm wrong :)

I did try

```
<name>yarn.client.failover-proxy-provider</name>
```

but no success

Any ideas?
Maybe I'm wrongly expecting client to find out active RM node?

Do You know howto switch node active/standby in 'auto-failover' option?

```
~/hadoop/bin/yarn  rmadmin -failover rm1 rm2
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RMHAServiceTarget doesn't have a corresponding ZKFC address

~/hadoop/bin/yarn  rmadmin -transitionToActive rm1 rm2
    Automatic failover is enabled for org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMHAServiceTarget@2b72cb8a
    Refusing to manually manage HA state, since it may cause
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable HA-RM in automatic fail-over mode, you cannot trigger active to stand-by or vice-verse. and you should provide `yarn.client.failover-proxy-provider` parameter, the class to be used by Clients to fail-over to the Active RM. And as well as configure `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` to identify the RM's (i.e, rm1 , rm2).

If automatic fail-over is not enables, you can trigger using below 
`yarn rmadmin -transitionToStandby rm1`

Please do above changes and give reply with result