# Hadoop connection refused to ResourceManager on localhost:8032

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop, and have been trying to get it working on my machine since the last several hours. I've mostly followed the installation and setup instructions from these guides - [1](http://dongfeiwww.com/hadoop/2014/09/05/hadoop-on-mac/), [2](https://isaacchanghau.github.io/post/install_hadoop_mac/), [3](https://medium.com/@jeremytarling/apache-spark-and-hadoop-on-a-macbook-air-running-osx-sierra-66bfbdb0b6f7), [4](https://macmetric.com/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac/), [5](https://dtflaneur.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-el-capitan/), [6](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

I have also read this SO question on [Hadoop: Connecting to ResourceManager failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586920/hadoop-connecting-to-resourcemanager-failed) several times, but nothing has helped.

Here are my configuration files:

**core-site.xml** -

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
   <!-- <value>/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value> -->
   <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
   <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property> 
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml** -

```
<configuration>

 <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>${user.home}/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>${user.home}/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml** -

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml** -

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8031</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The setup guides also require making changes in `hadoop-env.sh`, but the required changes are already present in this `case` for OSX, so I didn't make any further changes -

```
case ${HADOOP_OS_TYPE} in
  Darwin*)
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.realm= "
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.kdc= "
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.conf= "
  ;;
esac
```

In my `.zshrc` file, I've added the `hstart` and `hstop` alias like so -

```
# hadoop config
alias hstart="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/sbin/start-dfs.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/sbin/start-yarn.sh"
alias hstop="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/sbin/stop-yarn.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/sbin/stop-dfs.sh"
```

I think my `hstart` command is working normally -

```
➜  ~ hstart
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [Manish-Macbook-Pro-15.local]
2019-03-01 02:26:13,502 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

Here is the output of `jps` -

```
➜  ~ jps
30548 NameNode
31172 Jps
30796 SecondaryNameNode
30655 DataNode
```

After this, I try to run of the sample jar files (`hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.1.jar`) with a sample job from one of the guides -

```
➜  ~ cd /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce
➜  mapreduce hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.1.jar pi 2 5
```

This is when the `ConnectionRefused` error shows up -

```
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 5
2019-03-01 02:26:39,491 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
2019-03-01 02:26:42,134 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
2019-03-01 02:26:43,440 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:44,443 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:45,449 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:46,452 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:47,456 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:48,461 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:49,463 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:50,469 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:51,475 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:52,481 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:53,496 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:54,501 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:55,507 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:56,510 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:57,513 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:58,517 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:26:59,520 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:27:00,526 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:27:01,528 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:27:02,530 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-03-01 02:27:02,533 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.net.ConnectException: Call From Manish-Macbook-Pro-15.local/192.168.200.79 to localhost:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, while invoking ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication over null after 1 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 31316ms.
```

After this, it keeps trying to connect repeatedly. I have to open up a new terminal tab to execute `hstop`.

I have no idea what is causing this error. I've started from scratch with `hdfs namenode -format` several times, but each time the same error.

A few other observations I have -

- The guides mention that once hadoop is up and running, I can view the status of things (like ResourceManager) in a browser using the corresponding default ports, but I've tried several ports - `localhost:50070`, `localhost:8088` and many more, but nothing works.
- In the `yarn-site.xml` file, I've used `localhost:8032` as the value for `<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>`, but in my terminal logs, it shows `2019-03-01 02:26:48,461 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032.`. I don't know why it's `localhost/127.0.0.1:8032` instead of `localhost:8032`.

Here are the contents of `/etc/hosts` -

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: First off: Better tagging may improve your chance of getting an answer. In esence see if yarn is actually running(doesn't look like it) the yarn logs may give you a hints. I don't see Zookeeper either which irritates me a lot - maybe start by ensuring Zookeeper is running.

Comment: For mapreduce to work you need resourcemanger to be up and running before trying out example make sure you have yarn up. Your JPS doesn't show anything for yarn.?

Comment: @rbyndoor No, `jps` only shows 4 things - `Jps`, `DataNode`, `NameNode`, `SecondaryNameNode`.

Comment: @kai What more tags should I add? As I mentioned, I'm new to Hadoop, so I added the tags that I thought were relevant. I'm not sure what Zookeeper is, didn't come across it in any of the guides.

Comment: you need NameNode ,DataNode ,SecondaryNameNode (Storage)
And Resourcemanager, Nodemanager(Compute i.e mapreduce such applications). You first brush up involved components and and it's primary responsibility before directly jumping in to examples. If you want to try out examples then try hadoop sandbox or vm's.

Comment: Most hadoop components require a running Zppkeeper!  https://zookeeper.apache.org/  Its usually the first hadoop component to be started. Otherwise services won't start properly(sounds like it could be your problem, right?). For the tagging: you don't have coding problem but one related to system-adminstaration,right?